# Theory E Minor Dominant First Inversion

Tags: chords

I was wondering that the procedure to these type of questions. You have to take special care for these questions. Dominant in a minor key. Because i know you have to raise the 7th in a dominant triad/chord in a minor key. It is just which note needs to be raised and what is the procedure.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand your question. It seems to be interesting, and I would love to learn something from it, but I'm not sure I get the point.

Comment: "Because I know you have to raise the 7th..." -- usually you raise the _3rd_ of a dominant chord in a minor key.

Answer (score 1):

Disregard the fact that it's in a minor key. The dominant is built on the 5th, so in Em will be a B chord. To be convincing, it needs a leading note, which here will be D# rather than D, found in the natural minor scale. To be even more convincing, there'll be a tritone within the chord, making it B7. That triton is between D# and A. The 1st inversion puts the 3rd at the bottom, so, D#, F# A, B. Could this be your homework?

Comment: An exam question about the "dominant" chord will not get full marks for an answer about the "domimant 7th" - though what you say is correct *musically* of course.

Comment: That was just an extra bit. How could my answer have achieved more marks?